# How to know which Activity started the ItemizedOverlay class

Tags: android, android-maps

I would like to know how to find out which activity(class name) started my custom ItemizedOverlay class, from the AlertDialog in my custom ItemizedOverlay class. I have different activities with a MapView of different places. All the activities will automatically start the ItemizedOverlay class when the MapView is loaded. As such, I can't putExtra to intent.

Anyone knows if this is possible?

Here's my ItemizedOverlay constructor class (Please ignore the comments part, and for the alertdialog message part):

```
public class CustomItemisedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {

private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mapOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();

private Context context;

public CustomItemisedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker) {
    super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public CustomItemisedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
    this(defaultMarker);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mapOverlays.get(i);
}

@Override
public int size() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mapOverlays.size();
}

//AlertDialog for driving directions here
@Override
protected boolean onTap(int index) {
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    //Title of AlertDialog
    dialog.setTitle("Driving Directions");
    //Message of AlertDialog
    String className = getClass().getSimpleName().toString();
    dialog.setMessage(className);
    //Positive Button
    dialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // Handle launch of driving directions here
            /*String tappedLong = null;
            String tappedLat = null;
            String className = this.getClass().getSimpleName().toString();
            if(className == "amkActivity") {
                tappedLong = "1.363414";
                tappedLat = "103.9370256";

            } else if (className == "bedokActivity") {
                tappedLong = "1.3248498";
                tappedLat = "103.9370256";
            }


            Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
                    Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=" + tappedLat + "," + tappedLong));
            context.startActivity(intent);*/

        }
    });

    //Negative Button
    dialog.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    //Display AlertDialog when tapped
    dialog.show();
    return true;
}

public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
    mapOverlays.add(overlay);
    this.populate();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

use

```
mapView.getContext();
```

in constructor of itemizedoverlay..

this will return context of mapview page...

Comment: what is the mapView that you are referring to? Can't seem to get it.. =(

Comment: I can only use what you suggest in the MapView class. How to use it in the alertdialog in my custom ItemizedOverlay class?

Comment: i am useing custom itemizedoverlay.. and in the constructor of itemized overlay. i have pass mapview object as a argument. and i have used mapview.getcontext(); in constructor...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure how this works, but to get the name of the activity that started the CustomItemisedOverlay class, use

```
context.getClass().getSimpleName();
```

For example, I want to put the activity name into a String called className, I do this:

```
String className = context.getClass().getSimpleName().toString();
```

The reason why `context` is used is because of this line of code(can be found above):

```
private Context context;
```

Thus `context` here refers to the context of the activity that started the CustomItemisedOverlay class